# Only Showing 1 Row

Tags: php, mysql

So Im trying to Import data from my phpmyadmin server and trying to display different users and data. I have got this working but it would only show the 1st result and nothing else. I have taken a screenshot and will insert my code below.

Thanks,

cNTr1nity

Image (Website) - https://gyazo.com/c7ee16469f88406e6bd8c97532ff44aa?token=04f129fc8bd3d38adcb30e0fd261b618

Code -  https://pastebin.com/9P7VGBr5

```
My Code is stuffing up. Please find pastebin link
```

P.S DBConnect is just connecting the php file to the database.

P.P.S I am updating all my stuff to mysqli because of sql injection.

Comment: Learn basic PHP...

Comment: Only one thing i can suggest:- Don't use `mysql_*` , it'e deprecated+removed now. Try to use `mysqli_*` OR `PDO` along with `prepared statements`.Also don't give link of third-party.Paste your code here only which cause problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st :** `mysql_*` api is deprecated try to use `mysqli_*`  or PDO

**2nd :**  Run the `mysql_fetch_array()` in while loop like below

```
            while($userInfo=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$userInfo['userId']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$userInfo['userName']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$userInfo['userEmail']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$userInfo['Dev']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$userInfo['Admin']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$userInfo['Mod']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$userInfo['Helper']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
```

**Note :** Don't forgot to move your code to `mysqli_* or PDO`

Comment: An Error Came Up While Doing That. ' Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/ubuntu/workspace/admin/staff.php on line 96 '

Comment: your query failing due to some reason . try to debug it . put this line `$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

the first thing use pdo method msql is deprecated , second you not define 
$_SESSION['user'] you most give a value to this $_SESSION['user']

something like

$_SESSION['user'] = email_user_after_login

and in your query you change "where id = " to "where email = "

bad staff ! isset this means wherever you send in $_SESSION['user'] make you staff work

`if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }`
// you most compare this $_SESSION['user'] with something if you don't someone can start you session with a injection